# Loop through JSHandle@array PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

I get the list of objects like this:

```
var elements = await page.EvaluateExpressionHandleAsync($"document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input')");
```

It returns a `JSHandle@array`, how can I iterate through its items?

Answer (score 0):

That's an array in the browser. If you want to get that array on your site, you can use the `GetPropertiesAsync` method. It should be something like this:

```cs
var properties = await elements.GetPropertiesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var elementsArray = properties.Values.OfType<ElementHandle>().ToArray();
```